# Here are four observations of the reactions of four metals

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, reactivity

Here are four observations of the reactions of four metals.

Metal F and G react slowly with water
Metal H displaces metal G from its chloride salt solution
Metal E does not react with dilute acids
Metal H does NOT displace metal F from its sulphate salt solution.

What is their order of reactivity, starting from the most reactive metal to the least reactive metal?

F>H>G>E;  H>G>F>E;  H>E>F>G;  G>H>F>E;  None of these

I'm really unsure how to order them     I would say F>H>G>E but thats half guessing.
Can someone give me a clue to arrange them right?

Answer (score 3):

Before starting of with my reasoning , I must tell you that your answer ( whether guessed or logically reasoned ) looks correct according to me .

I am assuming that you are familiar with the Metal Reactivity Series ( if not look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reactivity_series) )

We shall take use of a well presented reactivity series :

[image: Picture]
<sub>(source: [wikispaces.com](https://sjesci.wikispaces.com/file/view/reactivity_series1.gif/159802325/reactivity_series1.gif))</sub>

Now to crack the answer clue by clue :

1.

> Metal F and G react slowly with water.

Hence F and G are somewhere at the top.

2.

> Metal H displaces metal G from its chloride salt solution

Clearly H>G.

3.

> Metal E does not react with dilute acids

E will come somewhere at the bottom half so F,G>E (from 1) and we can further say H>G>E (from 2)

4.

> Metal H does NOT displace metal F from its sulphate salt solution

This gives F>H.

Combine last two clues' result to get F>H>G>E .